# ggplot2: geom_smooth - object not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to plot the results of one of my models on R using geom_smooth. I run the following code:

```
ggplot() + geom_smooth(data = daily_move, method = "lm", formula = day_dist~poly(num_date, degree=2), aes(x = num_date, y = day_dist))
```

And I get the following error:

> Warning message:
> Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`
> Caused by error:
> ! object 'num_date' not found

However, this column exists in my dataset, here's the head of my table:

```
structure(list(id = c("ORB01", "ORB01", "ORB01", "ORB01", "ORB01", 
"ORB01"), date = structure(c(1678489200, 1678575600, 1678748400, 
1678834800, 1679180400, 1679266800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), num_date = c(0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 9), day_dist = c(0.037, 
0.136, 0.292, 0.475, 0, 0.161), day_speed = c(0, 0.026, 0.085, 
0.0975, 0, 0.0363157894736842)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The formula seems to work though, as I managed to run this:

```
lm(data = daily_move, day_dist~poly(num_date, degree = 2))
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: The formula works on the variables provided to `aes()`, so it'd have to be `formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 2)` in this case.

Comment: This worked indeed, didn't know that geom_smooth functioned that way, I almost never had to use it before. Thank you so much! :))